# Unable to add contact in phonebook

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I am trying to add name & phone number into phone book.It always displays **"Inserted"** but it never came up in **phonebook**.

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

                int index = ops.size();

                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                        .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(
                                ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, index)
                        .withValue(
                                ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                                mDetail.get(position).getName())
                        .withValue(
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                                mDetail.get(position).getPhone())
                        .withValue(
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
                        .build());

                try {
                    getContentResolver().applyBatch(
                            ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);

                    Toast.makeText(Detail_Activity.this, "Inserted..",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    Toast.makeText(Detail_Activity.this, e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

*Suggestions/Help would be highly appreciated*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the solution. It works!!

```
        String name = mDetail.get(position).getName();
        String phone = mDetail.get(position).getPhone();



                ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                        .newInsert(
                                ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValue(
                                ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE,
                                null)
                        .withValue(
                                ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME,
                                null).build());

                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                        .newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                        .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE,
                                StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
                        .build());

                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                        .newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                        .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE,
                                Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, phone)
                        .withValue(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
                        .build());

                try {

                    getContentResolver().applyBatch(
                            ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);

                    Toast.makeText(Detail_Activity.this,
                            "Contact Saved..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    Toast.makeText(Detail_Activity.this,
                            e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
```